# PyCharm, resolve a library from a project folder

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an ordinary library, presented in pypi. Inside it, there is a tricky way to resolve names in the modules that we import. 
If I install it to Python folder, in a common way, PyCharm resolves it, builds a skeleton and I get the auto-completion for it. 
But in our project, we are holding used libraries in a project folder and PyCHarm doesn't read and process the library. For this, I got the "unresolved references" inspection raising, and the red wave-line.

How can I make PyCharm resolve a library in a project folder?

Example:

```
MyProjectRoot
    -- external_libs
        --six.py
```

When I write:

```
from external_libs.six.moves import range
```

PyCharm marks "moved" with yellow and "range" with the red wave-line.

Comment: Try marking it as a source directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: Can you share an example please? Also, for now you can use https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html

Comment: Kacper, I know about disabling inspections and don't want to use it. I added an example to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately the `six` package creates special proxy objects to  load the underlying module when an attribute is fetched. Basically, the `external_libs.six.moves.range` function is just an alias for the built in range function. However that proxy setup seems to be done automatically by PyCharm when the library is installed, but I am not sure how it can be replicated manually.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the information that I found and with a way to get it working, however I suspect that there is a bug with the IDE because once I start editing the file, the problem occurs again.

Comment: Ok, I believe I finally found a solution that works without any problems. I've added a new answer, let me know if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves) for the `six` package:

> **Note**: In order to make imports of the form:
>
> `from six.moves.cPickle import loads work`
>
> six places special proxy
>   objects in in sys.modules. These proxies lazily load the underlying
>   module when an attribute is fetched.

Because of that, the base path resolver in PyCharm is not able to easily find the actual path to the modules that are being imported for this package and other that use the same approach.

---

In order to overcome this problem, PyCharm uses [**Typeshed Stubs**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed):

> Typeshed is a set of files with type annotations for the standard
>   Python library and various packages. Typeshed stubs provide
>   definitions for Python classes, functions, and modules defined with
>   type hints. PyCharm uses this information for better code completion,
>   inspections, and other code insight features.

The typeshed stubs which can be found in their [official repository](https://github.com/python/typeshed), serve as a lookup table. For example, if you are looking for the `range` function  from `six.moves` which is just an alias for the built in `range` function, they will help PyCharm know how to resolve it by specifying that when you type `from six.moves import range` that should be resolved to something like `from builtins import range`.

---

You can override the bundled typeshed stubs by following the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed).

**Example:**
If you want to use the `six` package and you have a folder structure like this:

```
six_reproduce
    |─── main.py
    │
    │
    ├───external_libs
    │   |────six.py
```

Go to the original typeshed repository an download the stubs that you need.
For python 3 the stubs for the `six` library can be found **[here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/3/six)**.

Download the folder and put it under `external_libs` so that your project structure becomes this:

```
six_reproduce
    |─── main.py
    │
    │
    ├─── external_libs
    │   |──── six
    │   │      |──── moves
    │   │      │
    │   │      |──── __init__.pyi
    │   │
    │   |──── six.py
```

PyCharm should now be able to resolve your imports!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("external_libs")
import six
```

Comment: That can't help within "design-time".